# webpack-dev-server on HTTPS page

Tags: webpack, https, webpack-dev-server

I can't get the websocket to work when the app is on HTTPS and the dev server is on HTTP.

I'm running webpack-dev-server on the default `http://localhost:8080`. My app runs on `https://myapp.test` and references `http://localhost:8080/js/app.js`. This works but when it tries to create the websocket connection it requests it on `https://192.168.178.20:8080/...` and that fails:

[image: failed requests screenshot]

`192.168.178.20` is my local IP address so when I manually change the `https` to `http` it loads correctly. And if I serve the exact same app over HTTP on `http://myapp.test` it's all hunkydory:

[image]

Alternatively if I set `devServer: { https: true }` in the webpack config that also works but only after I manually accept the self signed certificate.

Isn't there a way to load the socket on an HTTP connection from an HTTPS page?

Answer (score 1):

Forcing HTTPS is deliberate but there's an exception if `hostname===127.0.0.1`:

```
devServer: {
  host: '127.0.0.1'
}
```

See the [source code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/5cb545fdc64c9d4b8e557ca86e597db93b3f93f3/client-src/default/utils/createSocketUrl.js#L68).